# pySpark / Databricks - How to write a dataframe from pyspark to databricks?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, aws-glue

I'm trying to write a dataframe from a pyspark job that runs on AWS Glue to a Databricks cluster and I'm facing an issue I can't solve.

Here's the code that does the writing :

```
spark_df.write.format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", jdbc_url) \
  .option("dbtable", table_name) \
  .option("password", pwd) \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save()
```

Here's the error I'm getting :

```
[Databricks][DatabricksJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: \nno viable alternative at input '(\"TEST_COLUMN\"'(line 1, pos 82)\n\n== SQL ==\nCREATE TABLE MYDATABASE.MYTABLE (\"TEST_COLUMN\" TEXT
```

It seems that the issue comes from the fact the SQL statement is using the column name with double quotes instead of single quotes and it's failing because of that.
I thought simple things like that would be managed automatically by spark but it seems it's not the case.

Do you know how can I solve that issue please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you passing any query in variable `table_name`? if yes include that also in your post

Comment: No we are not passing any queries. The table_name variable is only the name of the table in databricks.